# Find function with domain all real numbers with no Taylor series centered at $0$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

What is a function with domain $(−∞, ∞)$ but that does not have a Taylor series centered at $0$? Why doesn’t this function have a Taylor series centered at $0$?

I tried $\ln(x)$ but the domain was wrong. Someone please help, I really don't understand Taylor series very well.

Comment: Any function that is not infinitely differentiable at the origin will not have a Taylor series about $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical example is $f(x):=e^\frac{-1}{x^2}$, with $f(0)=0$. You can prove that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ (the $n$th derivative) for every $n$ by induction. Thus, if $f$ had a Taylor series about $0$, we would have 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n=0
$$
for every $x$ in some neighbourhood of $0$, which is absurd since $f(x)=0$ only for $x=0$.

Comment: It has a Taylor series, but the series doesn't converge to the function.

Comment: @saulspatz Oh you're right, I suppose I misread what the question was asking. I'll leave it up in case the OP finds it useful.

Comment: Yes, I read the question that way too, at first, because taken literally, it seems awfully simple.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=|x|$

Domain is all real numbers, but derivative does not exist at 0.